# I want to call a function when another function is called

Tags: ajax, function

I can't solve it can any one help me?

```html
function a(){
  statements...
}

function b(){
  Statements....
}
```

a() and b() are two different functions. I don't have any control over function a(). I want to call the function b() that i have created whenever function a() is called.

Comment: Put function B inside of function A

Comment: Or, just put a call to B inside A.

Comment: Could you describe your scenario? Do you have access to modify `A()`? Is it in a class? Do you want to call `B()` before or after `A()`, etc?

Comment: No I don't have access to A() , and i want to call B() after A() is called. and it's in Ajax

Answer (score 2):

Just call a function like this:

```
if(functionA()) { //if functionA returns true then functionB gets called
    functionB();
}
```

Comment: that function is being called through Ajax in plugin i want to call another function using ajax when that function called.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function a()// create function a
  {

    echo b(); // call function b

  }

  function b()// create function b
  {

    echo "hello world";

  }


  echo a(); // call function a, and thereby call function b
```

In this example, I created two separate functions: function a and function b.

The code block of function a calls function b.

Therefore, when I call function a, I am calling function b.

In this example, when I call function a at the end, I will get "hello world".

Answer (score -1):

```
function a() {
    b();
    /* do what you want to do to A */
}

function b() {
    /* do what you want to do to B */
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be only `b();` in line 2?

Comment: I think that you have to define `function b` before `function a`.

Comment: You all right mates !

Comment: both the functions are separate A is being called with Ajax in a plugin. I want to call B when A is called.

Comment: You should consider precise the object of your request so and adding a tag AJAX in your subject

Comment: this is first time i post over hare. that is why i'm confused.